# Append values from one file to another using sed or awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed

i have a file say file1 with the following data

```
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
3.3.3.3
testserver.test.com
4.4.4.4
255.255.255.0
```

i want the first two ip's to add in say file2 in the below format

Expected output (file2)

```
DNS1=1.1.1.1
DNS2=2.2.2.2
```

Kindly help

Comment: what did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `Awk` statement as below,

```
awk 'NR==1||NR==2{$0="DNS"NR"="$0; print}' file1 > file2
```

am using the `awk` in-built variable `NR` to keep track on the line numbers `1` and `2` and add the string `DNS` with line number and printing the contents to `file2`.

Answer (score 1):

@catchvenki:try: A very slightly different(but inspired from Inian's code) from Inian's nice solution.

```
 awk 'FNR==1||FNR==2{print "DNS"FNR"="$0}'    Input_file > Output_file
```

I am directly printing here lines in spite of taking them to $0 and then print, then after printing all the lines putting them into Output_file.

Answer (score 1):

Another in awk:

```
$ awk '$0="DNS" ++i "=" $0; NR==2{exit}' file 
DNS1=1.1.1.1
DNS2=2.2.2.2
```

Explained:

- `$0="DNS" ++i "=" $0` modifies `$0` by prepending text to the beginning and uses the result of the placement for implicit print
- `NR==2{exit}` exits after the second record output